# Google Maps Tile Cutter forcing white background

Tags: leaflet, nuxt.js, photoshop

I am using leaflet. Since I cannot use image-overlay due to memory usage and zooming being slow on some browsers I would like to use two tile-layers.

This seems to work perfectly, but the only thing I cannot fix is getting my tiles to be transparent. Whenever I cut them in Photoshop by using Bramus' tile cutter script it automatically adds a white background.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

https://www.bram.us/2012/04/23/photoshop-google-maps-tile-cutter-script/

That's the script I am using.

So basically what I want is the tiles being cut exactly as this script does, but with a transparent background.

I tried removing the white background by using ImageMagick but that still leaves me with some pixels in various shades of grey around the black area's unfortunately so that is not working either.

```
for /R "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\map\name" %I in (*.png) do magick "%I" -fuzz 0.3%% -transparent #FFFFFF "%I"
```

Original image
[image: Original picture]

After ImageMagick - added green BG for reference
[image: After ImageMagick - added green BG for reference]

After ImageMagick original
[image]

I tried adding -trim, but then I still have edges around my arrows, and sometimes (see original image below) it even deleted the gray area with the black top-border.

Anyways, is there a alternative for my Photoshop script so I can still generate tiles but transparent? I couldn't really find one.

Comment: Have you tried -trim with a -fuzz if required. A example image would help.

Comment: You probably need to use PNG for your overlay tiles. Post some sample images if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question yesterday while trying to solve the same problem you are facing.

Today, I figured it out. Not sure if you still want the solution, but I'll post the edits here to the `PS_Bramus.GoogleMapsTileCutter.jsx` file so it justifies this answer. I have modified the original file further because I ONLY want the PNG with transparency option and don't care about any of the other settings.

```
// Flatten the image (speeds up processing if it were a non-flattened one yet)
// curDoc.flatten(); // FYI - flattening forces white background

// Unlock the one layer of the flattened image
//curDoc.activeLayer.isBackgroundLayer = false;
//curDoc.activeLayer.allLocked = false;

// keep track of all other snapshots
var snapshots = [];

// Resize to a square version & center image - this way we get an image size that's easily tileable (512, 1028, 2048, 4096, ...)
// var bgColorHex = new SolidColor();
// bgColorHex.rgb.hexValue = options.bgColor;
// app.backgroundColor = bgColorHex;
```

The reason the white background happens, even if after commenting out the background color stuff, is because the "flatten image" forces white behind it. If you take that out and remove all of the setting the background color stuff, it will end up being transparent.